# Как обработать множество файлов в контекстном меню Windows?

Tags: windows, реестр, regedit, contextmenu

У меня есть обработчик изображений, работающий с форматом `.png` в контекстом меню Windows 10 (конкретно сейчас - Windows 10 22H2)
Если выбирать небольшую группу файлов - всё работает отлично.
Однако, если я выбираю множество файлов (16 и более) - моё подменю пропадает из контекстного меню.

Меню создаю через файл `.reg` следующего содержания:

```
[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\*\shell\TexTools]
"MUIVerb"="Texture Tools"
"Icon"="cmd.exe"
"AppliesTo" = "System.FileName:*.png"
"ExtendedSubCommandsKey"="Directory\\ContextMenus\\TexTools"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\ContextMenus\TexTools\shell\split]
"MUIVerb"="Split"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\ContextMenus\TexTools\shell\split\command]
@="C:\\TexTools\\TexTools.exe -i \"%1\" -m split"
```

Пробовал убирать ключ AppliesTo, но это не даёт результата. Кроме того, я всё-ещё хотел бы, чтобы меню отображалось только когда выбраны файлы формата `.png`.

Как я понимаю, контекстное меню иначе работает с большим количеством выделенных файлов. Как это правильно обработать?